# Mechanic says lock is nonfunctional from broken power window?

Tags: door

My mom's car was broken into 2 days ago, both drivers side windows smashed. We sent the car to an auto glass technician to replace the windows and remove the glass fibers embedded in the seats.

They just called my mom and told her that the window mechanism is broken on the rear door, which I could see being possible. However they also said that the door latch was broken "because all the rods are connected" which is total bs imo, especially since we were opening and closing the door just fine before we took the car to them, and now they say that the door can't be opened? I am convinced that this is either their mistake that they are trying to get her to pay for, or that trying to pull a fast one on her. Or worse I wonder if they even damaged it on purpose so they could "fix it"?

I would like to know how to handle a situation like this where the technician is coming up with seemingly false facts, or even damaging property in an attempt to convince you to pay for additional services? I would also like to have people who know what they are talking about that verify a lock module doesn't have anything to do with a power windows mechanism.

Edit:
The mechanic just told us that the problem is the window regulator. I looked it up and it appears that the part is simply the mechanism that pushes the window up and down. The mechanic said that it controls everything in the door including the lock, and that when you open the door to service it the regulator "flys apart" and you have to replace it with a new one. He was also being extremely defensive when we asked any questions. Am I correct about the window regulator not being nearly as important and fragile as he makes it out to be?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It will be useful to know the make, model and year of the vehicle.

Comment: It's a 2011 Dodge Nitro

Answer (score 2):

The electrical window regulator is exactly what the name suggests; it is responsible for providing a frame which the window glass can slide up and down on and house the window motor.

If the door lock does not work any more it is highly unlikely that the window regulator is to blame.

Under normal circumstances, window regulators do not "fly apart" when taking the door off.

---

Here's how I would approach the mechanic's claim - it's hard to argue with facts:

- the door was functioning prior to taking the car in
- window regulators are designed to withstand a lot of load and repetitive abuse; exposing it to direct sunlight will not damage it
- if the car door has a manual lock, the mechanism is separate; if the car door has central-locking, the door lock actuator is separate

All the best.

Answer (score 2):

As Zaid says, the window regulator does not have any connection with the door lock control.

What I suspect has happened is that they had to disconnect the door locks from the inside handle in order to remove the door card (the inner cover on the door), and in doing so they broke something and are trying to avoid paying to repair it.

I would suggest finding out the official window replacement procedure (ideally in writing - perhaps your local Dodge dealer would help?), so that you know what they should have done, and let them know that you'll be involving trading standards and/or legal advice if they don't do it properly...